# TCL Expect SCP progress script

Tags: tcl, expect, scp

I am writing a script to transfer a TCL file from a server to a remote system. each file can take ~ 2 hours to transfer. The reason I am using `-re .` is so that during the progress it will match anything and update the timeout. So in 10 seconds, if there is no change, then it will end the script. So far I have this script:

```
set timeout 10
expect {
    -re ".*assword*." {
        send "${password}\r\r"
        exp_continue
    } "lost connection" {
        set success2 0
        set success1 0
    } "100%" {
        puts "File Transfer successful\n"
        set success1 0.5
        exp_continue
    } -re . {
        exp_continue
    } timeout {
        set success2 0
        set success1 0
    } -re ".*closed by remote host" {
        set success2 0.5
    }
}
# IF success1 + success2 = 1, then the transfer was successful.
```

The problem is that this only works sometimes. After the file is transferred 100%, I have to wait for the message `Connection close by remote host` before I can continue with the script. I believe the `-re .` matches something before this and ends the script. The time this message takes to display varies. Therefore I get the message could not find variable success2

Comment: Try moving that pattern higher in the list of patterns, before `-re .`

Comment: Tried that and ran it twice. Worked the first time, failed the second.

Comment: Turn on expect's debugging and see what it's doing: add this before that `expect` command: `exp_internal 1`

Comment: When I debug it with that code, it seems to be working well. It evaluates in an orderly manner. Going to run it a few more times and see if it breaks

Comment: And it broke again. It seems to work with smaller files, but it breaks with larger files. Is there another way of implementing this process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `expect -re .` you would probably not be able to match `-re ".*closed by remote host"` even you put this pattern before `-re .`. Can you `expect` the `NN%` string? For example:

```
set timeout 60      ;# more timeout since you're scp'ing big files
expect {
    -re ".*assword*." {
        send "${password}\r"    ;# why do you use ``\r\r''?
        exp_continue
    } "lost connection" {
        set success2 0
        set success1 0
    } "100%" {
        puts "File Transfer successful\n"
        set success1 0.5
        exp_continue
    } -re {[0-9]{1,2}%} {
        exp_continue
    } timeout {
        set success2 0
        set success1 0
    } -re ".*closed by remote host" {
        set success2 0.5
    } eof {
        set success2 0.5
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how you're `spawn`ing `scp`. My `scp` does not output the `closed by remote host` message. Maybe the `-re ".*closed by remote host"` part is not necessary so you can just keep the `eof` part.

Comment: This work around is awesome! expect there is one small caveat:
`expect: does " |******************************************************                                                                                            | 139 KB    10:17 ETA" (spawn_id exp10) match regular expression ".*assword*."? Gate "*asswor*"? gate=no
".*closed by remote host"? Gate "*closed by remote host"? gate=no
"100%"? no
"lost connection"? no
"[0-9]{1,2}%"? Gate "*%"? gate=no`. It does not see the % sometimes, therefore it does not hit that condition

Comment: That may indicate that the `**...**` part is not printed (e.g. by `printf`) at the same time as `NN%`. But I think it would still work. Do you mean my workaround sometimes failed to work?

Comment: It does work. Its just a thought that it may still break if it remains in that state for longer than the timeout. But I have been testing it and it has worked every time. I can get the max file size and calculate the minimum timeout. Thanks!

Comment: It just broke again. I find that it breaks in the time between the printing of  `File Transfer successful` and  `Connection closed by remote host`.

Comment: `File Transfer successful

expect: continuing expect

expect: does " |**...**|  1717 KB    01:16    \r\r\n" (spawn_id exp10) match regular expression ".*assword*."? Gate "*asswor*"? gate=no
".*closed by remote host"? Gate "*closed by remote host"? gate=no
"100%"? no
"lost connection"? no
"[0-9]{1,2}%"? Gate "*%"? gate=no
expect: read eof
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp10"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) " |**...**|  1717 KB    01:16    \r\r\n"
can't read "success2": no such variable`